# php require_once not finding file with absolute path?

Tags: php, require, require-once

I just started setting up the google ads php library and right off the bat am having super frustrating troubles.

I'm running Arch Linux, and I have all my files in /var/lib/googleads

Trying to run GetRefreshToken.php, it requires a file called init.php in the same directory.  Here is that line:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/init.php';
```

When I run this php file, I get this error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/lib/googleads/examples/AdWords/Auth/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /var/lib/googleads/examples/AdWords/Auth/GetRefreshToken.php on line 30

Even though as you can clearly see, the absolute path it's looking for is correct, and I even have it set at 777 permissions for now.

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.4K Nov 20 10:17 /var/lib/googleads/examples/AdWords/Auth/init.php

NO idea what's going on here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was quick, but I thought I'd post the answer for anyone else who runs across this problem.

PHP didn't have access to files in /var/lib, which I found is set by the open_basedir line in php.ini, so I added /var/lib to that line and all is working correctly.

> open_basedir = /var/www:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/var/named/:/root/:/var/lib/:

Hopefully this can help someone down the road!

Answer (score -1):

change this `(include_path='.:/usr/share/pear')` to its correct path in your init.php or GetRefreshToken.php

Comment: I did not downvote this. However, whenever someone downvotes an answer, then that person should be posting an answer themselves, seeing that they (probably) know "how" or at least say why it was downvoted; it's *just* the right thing to do.

Comment: I agree with you Fred... I don't know who downvoted this, but it wasn't me either :)

Comment: It is not important for me, if it is valuable for you :)